# How to create a pg_trgm index using SQLAlchemy for Scrapy?

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape data from a web forum. I am storing this data in a PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy. The table and columns create fine, however, I am not able to have SQLAlchemy create an index on one of the columns. I am trying to create a trigram index (pg_trgm) using gin.

The Postgresql code that would create this index is:

```
CREATE INDEX description_idx ON table USING gin (description gin_trgm_ops);
```

The SQLAlchemy code I have added to my models.py file is:

```
desc_idx = Index('description_idx', text("description gin_trgm_ops"), postgresql_using='gin')
```

I have added this line to my models.py but when I check in postgresql, the index was never created.

Below are my full models.py and pipelines.py files. Am I going about this all wrong??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

## models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Index, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
import settings

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()
def db_connect():
return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))

def create_forum_table(engine):
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)    


class forumDB(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    desc = Column('description', String, nullable=True)
    desc_idx = Index('description_idx', text("description gin_trgm_ops"), postgresql_using='gin')
```

## pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import forumDB, db_connect, create_forum_table


class ScrapeforumToDB(object):
def __init__(self):
    engine = db_connect()
    create_forum_table(engine)
    self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    session = self.Session()
    forumitem = forumDB(**item)

    try:
        session.add(forumitem)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

    return item
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the `Index` definition uses `text` expression it has no references to the `Table` "table", which has been implicitly created by the declarative class `forumDB`. Compare that to using a  `Column` as expression, or some derivative of it, like this:

```
Index('some_index_idx', forumDB.title)
```

In the above definition the index will know about the table and the other way around.

What this means in your case is that the `Table` "table" has no idea that such an index exists. Adding it as an attribute of the declarative class is the wrong way to do it. It should be passed to the implicitly created `Table` instance. The attribute [`__table_args__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration) is just for that:

```
class forumDB(DeclarativeBase):

    __tablename__ = "table"
    # Note: This used to use `text('description gin_trgm_ops')` instead of the
    # `postgresql_ops` parameter, which should be used.
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('description_idx', "description",
              postgresql_ops={"description": "gin_trgm_ops"},
              postgresql_using='gin'),
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    desc = Column('description', String, nullable=True)
```

With the modification in place, a call to `create_forum_table(engine)` resulted in:

```
> \d "table"
                                 Table "public.table"
   Column    |       Type        |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer           | not null default nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying | 
 description | character varying | 
Indexes:
    "table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "description_idx" gin (description gin_trgm_ops)
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work for me.
I allways get a `data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"`
The Index in question is created with `Index('sticker_text_gin_idx', text('text gin_trgm_ops'), postgresql_using='gin')` and the column is a simple `text = Column(String)`

Comment: The error would indicate that you're not actually passing `gin_trgm_ops` (or other operator class) somewhere where you should. Without a traceback, models to go with that etc. it is hard to say more than that.

Answer (score 16):

The proper way to reference an [Operator Class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#operator-classes) in SQLAlchemy (such as `gin_trgm_ops`) is to use the `postgresql_ops` parameter. This will also allow tools like [alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/) to understand how use it when auto-generating migrations.

```
Index('description_idx',
      'description', postgresql_using='gin',
      postgresql_ops={
          'description': 'gin_trgm_ops',
      })
```