# Create multi-column Postgresql trgm index and filter based on that in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, sqlalchemy, full-text-search

Assume we install the `pg_trgm` extension

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

And then create an index on the `user` table

```
CREATE INDEX user_search_idx 
   ON user USING gin (first_name gin_trgm_ops, last_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

How would I create such an index in `sqlalchemy` (This is similar to [this answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36389792/2386605)) based on two columns?

Furthermore, assume I would have a string like `word1 word2 word3`. How do query the `user` table in sqlalchemy, such that `word1, word2,`  and `word3` are all contained either in `first_name` or `last_name` either case-insensitive (perhaps something like `ilike`) or by imperfect similarity.

Comment: I don't think you can have a substring similarity match. That's too vague.

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me. What do you mean by too vague?

Comment: I'm not sure. AT any rate, I don't think it is possible.